# How do I change JVM Options for one Gradle Task/project?

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, build.gradle

I have a set of gradle projects and subprojects. I'm trying to change the JVM args for one single subproject, because it is a set of unit tests that require a large amount of memory - so I want to add `'-Xms2g -Xmx4g'` to the VM opts when I execute just that target.

Is there a way to do that? The only specific ways that I've found in the documentation are to set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` in the environment, or `org.gradle.jvmargs="-Xms2g -Xmx4g"` in the `gradle.properties` script, but both of those cause *all* of the targets to use those options.

I'm pretty new to gradle, so pointers to specific docs that cover per-task properties are particularly welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with any task that implements [JavaForkOptions](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/JavaForkOptions.html).

```
test {
    minHeapSize = '2g'
    maxHeapSize = '4g'
}
```

Comment: I need to run unit tests with different timeZone at one sub module. So I update like this:

test{
jvmArgs '-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.timezone="Asia/Colombo"'
}
But stil it's not getting what I changed. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to change timeZone only for specific sub project, setting like this solved problem.

```
test{
    systemProperty "user.country", "US"
    systemProperty "user.language", "en"
    systemProperty "user.timezone", "Asia/Colombo"

    useTestNG() {
        suites "src/test/resources/testng.xml"
    }
}
```